Does anyone have suggestions or recommendations on how to integrate CKEditor 5 Full page HTML plugin successfully into a Drupal website?
I am exploring ways to implement the Full Page HTML feature of CKEditor 5 in Drupal. Does anyone have suggestions or recommendations on how to integrate this feature successfully into a Drupal website?
I'm trying to integrate the Full page HTML feature with CKEditor 5 into our Drupal page but this plugin is not yet available in Drupal implementation. I wonder if there are other ways or the last option would be to create a Drupal module. I am new to designing custom Drupal modules and was hoping this community might provide me some help or information so I could get started.
In the previous version of CKEditor, we tried to create a yml file to set a default value of the HTML tags in the content. Aside from this, we use CKEditor Custom Config module to set the config.fullPage option to true.
Upon clicking the Source Editing toolbar button, the HTML source of the content will be viewed and edited.

This is what happens using previous CKEditor version 4 and what I want to achieve when clicking Source Editing button.
Note: The editor is in Full HTML input format.
When I type text into the editor and click that button, the entire HTML tags should appear on the editor.

On the other hand, when I type a text into editor using the latest version CKEditor 5, the behavior will be as follows:

It will only show the elements inside the content or document's <body> tag such as <p>, <strong>, etc.

You can't. This is technically just not possible, CKeditor in Drupal can (must!) only edit individual fields, but not the entire site. This would break a lot of Drupal concepts like regions, blocks, attachments/libraries, caching,.....

This sounds like a use-case for Gatsby or similar, not Drupal

Actually, I think the plugin the OP is talking about lets you author complete page HTML in CKEditor, not the current page.

@Hudri we are trying to edit the entire HTML page not the entire site.

For example, in Drupal, I have an article content type that I wanted to create such that when I click the Source Editing button, the complete HTML tag appears.

Hi @cilefen sorry for the confusion. To make things clear, what we are doing is on the node body field and we are saving an HTML content that's why we need the tags from to to be preserved in Drupal using CKEditor 5. Do you know whether there's any way to do that? Thanks.

I think the question would be improved by removing all but the first two paragraphs.
